# horizontal menu is wrapping

Tags: css, responsive-design

my horizontal menu is wrapping when I resize the browser. I'm new to responsive web and I've tried the other suggestions that are mentioned previously and nothing worked. Any suggestions will be extremely helpful.
My code is in this jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/47cfL0ka/

My code:
     ---------------CSS----------------------

```
 body{margin:0 auto;padding:0;font: 13px Arial,sans-serif;}
 .clear{clear:both;}
 p,ul,li,a,h1,h2,h3,h4{margin:0;padding:0;}
 h1,h2,h3{margin:10px 0;}
 img.bor{border:#000000 solid 1px;}
 .wrap{margin:0 auto;width:100%;height:auto; border-right:0px solid 
 #FFF;border-left:0px solid #FFF;display: block;}

*{box-sizing: border-box;}
 .row::after {
 content: "";
 clear: both;
 display: table;
 }
[class*="col-"] {
float: left;
padding: 15px;
}
.col-1 {width: 8.33%; }
.col-10 {width: 83.33%; background-color:#ffffff;}
.col-12 {width:100%;}

.header{position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;display:block;}
.title{position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;display:block;}
img {max-width: 100%; height: auto;}

 #dropdownMenu,
 #dropdownMenu ul {list-style: none;}
 #dropdownMenu {display:inline-block; width:100%;}
 #dropdownMenu > li {display:inline-block; height: 2.5em; line-height:2em;
  padding: 0 0em;    text-decoration: none;font-size: 1em;}
 #dropdownMenu li a{display: block;   height: 2.5em;  width:4em; 
 line-height: 2em;  padding: 0 0em; text-decoration: none;font-size: 1em; }
 #dropdownMenu ul {position:absolute; display: none;z-index: ; padding: 0; }

 #dropdownMenu li:hover ul {display: block;}

  /* Main menu------------------------------------------*/
 #dropdownMenu {font-family: Arial; background-color:lightblue;}
 #dropdownMenu > li > a {color: #fff;font-weight: bold;}
 #dropdownMenu > li:hover > a {background: #f09d28;color: #ffffff; } 
 #dropdownMenu li:hover ul.dropdown {display: block; }    /*dropdown*/
 #dropdownMenu a:active ul.dropdown {display: block; }    /*dropdown*/
 #dropdownMenu > li:hover{background: #f09d28;}
 #dropdownMenu li.parentmenu, #dropdownMenu li.parentmenu:hover 
 {padding-top: 4px; width: 13.2em;border-bottom:0px; text-align: 
 center;color: #fff;font-weight: bold; }

 #dropdownMenu a.parentmenu, #dropdownMenu a.parentmenu:hover 
{padding-top: 4px; width: 13.2em;border: 0px; text-align: center; }

/* Submenu------------------------------------------*/
#dropdownMenu ul {background: #ffffff;}
#dropdownMenu ul li a {color: #727272;}
#dropdownMenu ul li:hover a {background: #f0d84f; }

#dropdownMenu a.bord, #dropdownMenu a.bord:hover    
   {border: 1px #d2d2d2; border-bottom: dotted 1px #d2d2d2; border-top: 0px; 
   border-right:solid 1px #d2d2d2; border-left:solid 1px #d2d2d2; 
  height:auto; width: 14.2em;text-align:left;padding:0 0 0 15px;}



   /********HTML CODE**********************/
 <body>
   <!--wrap starts-->
     <div class="wrap">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
        </div>

      <!-- header starts-->
        <div class="col-10">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="title">
                    <img src="Images/Title.gif"  alt="welcome" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
        <!--mainmenu starts-->

  <ul id="dropdownMenu">   
   <li class="parentmenu">About Us
      <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#" class="bord">Contact Us</a></li>            
          <li><a href="#" class="bord" >Deals</a></li>            
          <li><a href="#" class="bord">Wheelz</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="bord">Toyz</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"  class="bord">Gears</a></li>            
          <li><a href="#" class="bord">About Us</a></li>            
          <li><a href="#" class="bord">FAQ </a></li>
      </ul> 
   </li>    

    <li class="parentmenu">Related stuff       
        <ul class="dropdown">
             <li><a href="#" class="bord">LM</a></li>            
             <li><a class="bord" href="#" class="bord" >BLC</a></li>            
             <li><a href="#" class="bord">Bjh</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" class="bord">AM</a></li>            
             <li><a href="#" class="bord">Nm</a></li>            
             <li><a href="#" class="bord">SiS</a></li>                 
             <li><a href="#" class="bord">PM</a></li>            
          </ul> 
          </li> 
          <li><a href="#" class="parentmenu">BQ?</a></li>  
          <li><a href="#" class="parentmenu">LL</a></li>  
          <li><a href="#" class="parentmenu">What's New?</a></li>    
          <li><a href="#" class="parentmenu">Contact Us</a></li>
         </ul>
            <!--mainmenu ends-->
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div><!--wrap ends-->
</body>
```

Comment: it is plenty of solutions out there, cannot believe any of them worked... show here one of those you tried and people will be more able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is a horizontal menu, treat it as a CSS table:

```
#dropdownMenu {
  display: table;
  table-layout: auto; /* Container */
}
#dropdownMenu > li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle; /* Each item is a "cell" */
}
#dropdownMenu > li > a {
  white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent text from wrapping into multiple lines */
  padding: 1em;
}
```

Comment: @GianlucaManici it worked. Thank you! I kept trying with diplay-inline and no wrap. Did not get anywhere. Thanks again.